# Python: removing old records and duplicates between two CSV files

Tags: python, csv

Total beginner with Python, need help to achieve a task!

I have two csv files. old.csv and new.csv

Both have same structure (A to Z columns), and each record has a unique identifier which is a number, in column F (sixth column). Between these two CSVs there are a few duplicates records.

I’m looking for a way to eliminate records that are also in the old.csv, from the new.csv and output to a new file that has the same structure, so the new output.csv has truly only the new records.

What's a good way to achieve this? I need to be able to run this on a windows machine through a command line.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to remove the duplicate identifier in new.csv and output to another file? am i right?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

Read the csv file and map it to tuple

```
import csv

f = open('old.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)
reader =  map(tuple,reader)

fn = open('new.csv', 'rb')
readern = csv.reader(fn)
readern = map(tuple,readern)
```

Get all unique identifiers in old.csv

```
from operator import itemgetter
reader= map(itemgetter(5), reader)
```

add all items whose identifier is not in old.csv, add them to unique list

```
unique= [item for item in readern if item[5] not in reader]
```

Write the rows to output.csv

```
output = open("output.csv", 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(output)
for row in unique:
        wr.writerow(row)
output.close()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be:

- collect all identifiers from old.csv in a set
- loop through new.csv
- if a record has an identifier that's noz in your set, write it to output.csv

You will probably want to use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for reading and writing the files.